# Delaying a while loop

Tags: java, android, while-loop, wait

(Android) How can I make a loop waiting a short time (like half an sec.) before doing another loop?

```
void replaceText(String s)
{
    doSomething1();
    int x = 0;
    while (x < 5)
    {
        doSomething2();
        x++;
    }
    doSomething3();
}
```

So what I want is that my app "waits" a short time after the method doSomething2(). Google could't help me this time:D

Comment: `Thread.sleep()` should be rarely used and is certainly not appropriate in this case, nor on the main thread.

Answer (score 3):

You can try using a Handler

```
   // Execute some code after 1 second have passed
            Handler handler = new Handler(); 
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
                 public void run() { 
                      doSomething2();
                 } 
            }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want your while loop to be executed every 1000ms for example, you can do this:

```
final Handler handler=new Handler();
Runnable r=new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        doSomething2(); 
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);              
    }
};

handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
```

This will execute `doSomething2()` every 1000ms.

---

Specific to your example, you can try the following option as well:

```
void replaceText(String s)
{
    doSomething1();
    int x = 0;
    while (x < 5)
    {
        Thread.sleep(100);
        doSomething2();
        x++;
    }
    doSomething3();
}
```

Note that since Thread.sleep stops the thread, make sure you run this function on a non-UI thread. A naive implementation for this will be:

```
void replaceText(String s)
{
final String str = s;
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
               // user str instead of s;
               doSomething1();
               int x = 0;
               while (x < 5)
                   {
                      Thread.sleep(100);
                      doSomething2();
                      x++;
                   }
               doSomething3();
          }
    };

    thread.start();

}
```

Comment: I was going to post the same thing!
I think this is the best way to do that, sleeping the main thread will cause a "zombie like" application

Comment: You can use Thread.sleep as long as the function is not executed on the main UI Thread.

Answer (score -1):

```
Thread.sleep(500);
```

Will cause your code to sleep for half a second before continuing. Note that you will then need to handle the `InterruptedException` appropriately.

Comment: `Thread.sleep()` should be rarely used.  This is not an appropriate usage.  Never freeze the main thread.

Comment: @Simon can you give me some references describing why it shouldn't be used? I mean, other than the fact that sleeping is sometimes used to attempt to avoid some sort of race condition and slows down execution. (Genuinely looking to learn)

Comment: 1.  It freezes the UI thread, which affects performance of the app and might cause an ANR.  2.  It's not needed.  3.  it stops the coder from thinking about, and coding, the correct design.  https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=thread.sleep+is+bad, http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2009/05/painless-threading.html